# List and positions python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a function which takes a list of positions from a word in a list and prints the word itself with the one before/after. So, for example [2, 4, 7] needs to print:

*cherry banana soup*

*soup banana coffee*

*water banana sugar*

since "banana" is found in positions 2, 4, 7.

```
# my code
positions = [2, 4, 7] 
list = ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'soup', 'banana', 'coffee', 'water', 'banana', 'sugar']  

def context(positions, list):        
    empty_string = ''         
    for item in positions:               
        emprty_string += item[-1], item, item[+1]
```

Comment: i don't understand what needs to be reversed. and post your code even if it doesn't work

Comment: `enumerate()` could be helpful. https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/

Comment: Let's try to avoid using the builtin `list` as program variable. It could cause some problem...

Comment: yes, you are right. I am new to python and still learning everything

Comment: Another note, the fruit in the `list` should be string type like `'apple'`, unless those are defined earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I have another long list of words that I am working with, this was just a short example, I forgot to put the quotation marks here.

Comment: What about the first and the last positions that don't have a before and after?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this quite straight-forward. Just iterate over the `positions` (also known as **indicies**) and fetch the previous, current and next element directly from the list. Side note: don't  name the variable `list` as you are overriding the built-in class `list`.

```
def context(indices, items):
    return [f'{items[i - 1]} {items[i]} {items[i + 1]}' for i in indices]
```

If you're not comfortable with list comprehension, this is another variant:

```
def context(indices, items):
    result = []
    for i in indices:
        #             previous     current       next
        string = f'{items[i - 1]} {items[i]} {items[i + 1]}'
        result.append(string)
    return result
```

This also uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to concatenate the items into a string (only for Python 3.6 or greater), but you can of course change this to any form of concatenation you're comfortable with.

Comment: awesome! this is actually quite easy, thank you!!

Comment: @emily Not though that this doesn't do any error handling. If your indices has an index to the first or last element, then this function will crash or output the wrong result.

Comment: I have checked it now and it works with the text that I am using. But I don't need to do anything else for this exercise, just print that output.

Comment: @emily If this answer helped you, consider marking it as accepted/solved.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work :-

```
lst = ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'soup', 'banana', 'coffee', 'water', 'banana', 'sugar']

def context(pos, lst):
    res, temp = tuple(), ""

    for i in pos:
        temp += (lst[i-1] + f" {lst[i]} " + lst[i+1])
        res += (temp,)
        temp = ""

    return res

for i in context(pos, lst):
    print(i)
```

Here it iterates through the positions' list and gets the corresponding value from the words' list and concatenates the adjacent words.

Comment: While this will work, it's not very efficient. Instead of iterating just 3 times it actually iterates 3 * 9 = 27 times! For bigger lists it'll be very slow. That along with both string and tuple concatenation will be very hard on performance.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Thanks for noting me; the algorithm has been improved.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
positions = [2, 4, 7] 
mylist = ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'soup', 'banana', 'coffee', 'water', 'banana', 'sugar']  

def context(positions = positions, mylist = mylist):
    want = [] # list of lists
    want2 = [] # or single list
    for i in range(len(positions)):
        tmp = mylist[(positions[i] - 1):(positions[i] + 2)] # before + after
        want.append(tmp)
        want2.append(' '.join(tmp))
    return want, want2    

context()[0]
#[['cherry', 'banana', 'soup'],
# ['soup', 'banana', 'coffee'],
# ['water', 'banana', 'sugar']]

context()[1]
#['cherry banana soup', 'soup banana coffee', 'water banana sugar']
```

Comment: oh great! Thank you so much